# Should a search engine friendly URL support Unicode characters or not?

Tags: seo, google-search, url, google-ads, unicode

I have my personal blog written in the Bengali language, where I have customized my content page's URL with exact keywords whenever I post a new article there.

Since the Bengali language is not supported by Google AdWords and Unicode characters are used, is this OK to do?

Should a search engine friendly URL support Unicode characters or not?

Answer (score 1):

Per the applicable standard, RFC 1378, URLs can only contain ASCII characters. Good explanation **[URL Encoding](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm)**:

> "...Only alphanumerics [0-9a-zA-Z], the special characters "$-_.+!*'()," [not including the quotes - ed], and reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL."

Use percent encoding with **[URL Decoder/Encoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)**.